# Jquery replace html, only where changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ace-editor

I am cloning a realtime markdown editor, **[dillinger.io](http://dillinger.io)**, but in unlike in dillinger when you have embedded a video in the document, but I dont want the video to refresh and flash every time the document is updated, which is very often.

The way the DOM is organized is as follows.

```
<div id='editor'></div>
<div id="viewer">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe> <!-- Gangnam style youtube embed-->
    <p>What a dull video</p>
</div>
```

The editor in this case is the wonderful [Ace editor](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about), which allows me to get the writing inside it by `editor.getValue()`

Is there an easy known way to do this? I have Googled, found nothing that useful.

This is what I have at the moment

```
function update(){
    var mk = editor.getValue();
    var updatedHtml = converter.makeHtml(mk);
    $('#viewer').html(updatedHtml); 
}

editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
    update();
});
```

But I would like to change it to something like this

```
function update(){
    var before = $('#viewer').html();   
    var mk = editor.getValue();
    var updateHtml = converter.makeHtml(mk);
    $('#viewer').replaceWhereDifferent(updateHtml, before); 
}
```

what this would do is stop embedded youtube videos from flashing every time the update happens.

The problem is that I do not have a nice form for the function

`replaceWhereDifferent(updateHtml, before)`

Some example html strings would be

```
<div id="viewer">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe> <!-- Gangnam style youtube embed-->
    <p>comment</p>
</div>
```

Now say the user changes the p comment to

```
<p>OMG thats the best video ever</p>
```

I want that to update without refreshing the video

All of this is code is being generated by a markdown comverter taking code from the [Ace editor](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about). So all the markdown is converted together and I cannot discriminate or tag different pieces of the markdown. All I get is the updated html string

Comment: Any example code? Every situation is unique.

Comment: well I am looking for a solution...so I have no code, I will give more detail

Comment: More specifically, what are the two html strings? That's slightly vague.

Comment: What is your DOM layout? (How is the page broken up?)

Comment: have added more, essentially im reading code from an [Ace editor](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about), running it through a markdown converter and replacing the content of the div #viewer

Comment: After some research I've found that you can do what you're asking. Don't quote me but you fiddle around with this:

`editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
    editor.find('comment');
editor.replace('new_comment');
});`

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to change the values in the editor, I am reading them and printing them in the #viewer div. So the replacement is upon the #viewer div, which is why I want to replace only the changed html

Comment: Check out http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can make use of [Google's Incremental DOM](https://github.com/google/incremental-dom) or you can take a look at  [s9e TextFormatter](https://github.com/s9e/TextFormatter/blob/c79e98b41fd5517d79d29d0580f2411cce33d56e/src/render.js) used by Flarum and extract parts that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Put an attribute on your DOM elements that contains a timestamp for when they were last updated. Increase the timestamp when an actual change is made, only update the DOM if the timestamp is different.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easy" way. You'll have to Diff the two bits of html and then do fancy things with the delta.

I would take a completely different approach to the problem:

1. When you want to update the html, use jQuery to place the video markup HTML inside a new DIV.
2. replace all the HTML using a simple string replace or .html() or whatever.
3. put the video markup back where it's supposed to be.

e.g.

```
$('#placeholder').html($('#videodiv').html()); //1.
$('#divtoupdate').load("/URL/for/newdata");    //2
$('#videodiv').html($('#placeholder').html()); //3
```

Comment: If you would guess, how slow/fast would this be?

Comment: I think you would still get a flash when you move, replace the video, essentially I want to video to be untouched in the update.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the extra information. Now we have a clearer picture. If you just want to replace the `<p>` that's easy.

JS:

```
$('#add_comment').click(function(){ //User clicks add comment
  var comment = $('#comment_input').val(); //Get user's comment
  $('#viewer p').html(comment); //update viewer's <p>
});
```

I hope this gives you an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: That solution will not work for me, because I do not have access to the individual p tags, all of the old and updated html comes as blocks